# How to use async/await inside promise - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here's my method:

```
async sendEmail() {
  this.isActive = true
  this.$validator.validate().then(result => {
    if (result) {
      await axios.post('url', data)
      this.isActive = false
    }
  })
}
```

I'm showing the loader when `isActive = true`, but using `await` inside `this.$validator` throw me an error about word `await` is reserved. For validation i use [VeeValidate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/)

How can i use await inside `$validator` promise?

Comment: You can use `await` only inside an `async` function. So, try changing it to: `this.$validator.validate().then(async (result) =>{}`

Comment: @adiga, no error, but it doesn't work as intended, it should set `isActive` to false, after axios request, but `isActive` is always true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `await` keyword directly inside a function that isn't async. You are using the `await` keyword directly inside the anonymous function which is `then`'s parameter; this anonymous function isn't `async`, so you have a syntax error.

Here's how I would rewrite this function:

```
async sendEmail() {
  this.isActive = true
  let result = await this.$validator.validate();
  if (result) await axios.post('url', data);
  this.isActive = false;
}
```

I find it's cleaner to avoid using `then` when you're already inside an `async` function.

Btw, I'm not sure where your `data` variable is defined.

Comment: `data` is defined, there's no problem with it. Now it works, thanks. Btw, is it ok to use `try {} catch {}` inside `async` functions? e.g. `if (result) { try { ... } catch {...} }`

Comment: Yes `try` and `catch` will work exactly as you would expect them to!