# Use async/await inside promise.then

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to use Async Await after a promise returns a value. Unfortunately I am getting 'Parsing Error : Unexpected Token t2'.

I am not exactly sure what the issue is.

```
async function t1(){
  let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
  const results = [];
  return db.query(query)
    .execute()
    .then(res => {
      return Promise.map(res, r =>{
        results.push(await t2(r));
      });
    return results;
  });
}

function t2(event){
   return Promise.resolve()
    .then({
      //do something
    })
    .then({
      //promise chaining. do something more
    })
}

t1();
```

I tried understanding from [here](https://blog.adriaan.io/make-async-await-work-in-promises.html) but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I want to resolve my promises sequentially, i.e., t2(res[0]) should be executed first. Then after it returns a value, t2([res[1](https://blog.adriaan.io/make-async-await-work-in-promises.html)) should be called and so on

Comment: `return Promise.map(res, r =>{` but `Promise` is not an array..? What are you trying to map there?

Comment: the result I am getting from the query, 'res' , its an array

Comment: I am using Promise.map function from bluebird (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

Comment: Use `Promise.all` to wait for all Promises in an array to resolve, eg `res => Promise.all(res.map(t2))`

Comment: But I want to resolve my promises sequentially, i.e., `t2(res[0])` should be executed first. Then after it returns a value, `t2([res[1])` should be called and so on

Comment: `for (const r of res) results.push(await t2(r))`

Comment: Still getting `'Parsing Error : Unexpected Token t2'.`

Comment: Make sure the function is `async`, you can only `await` in an `async` function

Comment: Thanks. Got help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53921045/how-to-use-async-await-inside-promise-vue and the issue has been fixed